# convert Linux machine into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, clonezilla

I'm having trouble converting a physical CENTOS 6 machine into VirtualBox VM.

I followed this: https://www.linux.org/threads/physical-to-virtual-p2v-using-virtualbox.10928/
which uses Clonezilla and VboxManage

I can create the image with Clonezilla but when I run VBoxManger I get the error:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.uncomp.aa target.vdi
Converting from raw image file="sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.uncomp.aa" to file="target.vdi"...
Creating dynamic image with size 553033589122 bytes (527414MB)...
VBoxManage: error: VD: The given disk size 553033589122 is not aligned on a sector boundary (512 bytes)
VBoxManage: error: Error code VERR_VD_INVALID_SIZE at /home/vbox/vbox-5.2.26/src/VBox/Storage/VD.cpp(6220) in function int VDCreateBase(VDISK*, const char*, const char*, uint64_t, unsigned int, const char*, const VDGEOMETRY*, const VDGEOMETRY*, const RTUUID*, unsigned int, VDINTERFACE*, VDINTERFACE*)
VBoxManage: error: Cannot create the disk image "target.vdi": VERR_VD_INVALID_SIZE
```

When I searched for solutions to "not aligned on a sector boundary (512 bytes)", all I found said to use the linux command dd with bs and conv=sync flag but they set bs to be larger than the disk.  My disk is too big to use bs with a large number (e.g., 600G).  When I run:

```
dd if=sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.uncomp.aa of=padded-sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.uncomp.aa bs=600G conv=sync
```

I get error:

```
dd: memory exhausted
```

How do get around the 512 boundary issue?

Comment: I can't see why `bs=512` or any larger multiple of 512 would not work for the padding. 600G seems way off the scale and might well be the reason for dd saying `memory exhausted`.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach:

1. Create an empty disk image roughly the same size as the original. When in doubt, make it too large rather than too small. Attach it to the VM.
2. Boot the VM from a rescue disk ISO which contains Clonezilla (Clonezilla LiveCD, GRML, Ubuntu will work too but you'll have to install Clonezilla from the Internet).
3. Make the disk image on the host accessible over the network in guest. On a Linux host you can use sshfs, for Windows host network share will be the easiest way.
4. Configure VM's network card to host-only or NAT. Find host's IP.
5. Run Clonezilla on the guest and mount this shared resource as a working directory (`/home/partimag`). Clonezilla will assist you both with ssh-based share and Windows network share (samba).
6. Use Clonezilla to restore guest's disk from the image.